# Function that checks the value of my roof that was selected and give me the output can be customized

Tags: php, mysql, web

i work on web application in php. The application will be the estimates of works on roof. the app is app.tettosano.com/php_test/  when the user select its roof, then draw the roof on google maps, useful for measure the roof's area, and then on the basis of the choice of the roof, the user can make customizations.
Now, the code not work, there is no passage of value, but the code of choice the roof is

```
<div class="container">
<!--<div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel">-->
        <div class="carousel-inner" style="margin-left:1px !important;">
          <div class="item active">
          <form action="rooftype1.php" method="get">
          <?php
  $sql=mysql_query("select * from add_building where btype = '" . $buiding_type ."'");

  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))

  {
?>
                <ul class="thumbnails">
                    <li>

                        <div class="thumbnail">
                          <h5><?php echo $row['bname'] ?></h5>
                            <img src='admin/upload/<?php echo $row['bimage'];?>'/>

                            <div class="caption">
                            <p>Far far away behind the world mountains, far from the countries.</p>
                            </div>
                         <div>  <label class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $row['b_id']; ?>" name="check" > Seleziona il tetto
  </label></div>
                         <div> Esiste la copertura in amianto ?</div>
                     <div>
                        <label class="radio"><input type="radio" /> Si</label>
                        <label class="radio"><input type="radio" /> No</label>
                         </div>
                        </div>
                        </li>                       
                      <?php } ?>
                </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would need a function that checks the value of my roof that was selected and give me the output can be customized.
How can i to solve this issue?

Comment: PSA: The `mysql_*` functions are deprecated in PHP 5.5. It is not recommended for writing new code as it will prevent you from upgrading in the future. Instead, use either MySQLi or PDO and be a better PHP Developer.

Comment: Ok Timothy, i will do this.